# MvvmLight RaisePropertyChanged("")

Tags: c#, mvvm-light

As per [MSDN doc on PropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx), if you pass an empty string to the method, all properties are refreshed. Is there such a thing when using MvvmLight RaisePropertyChanged? Passing "" just throw the event with "".

Comment: please read the article [ask] ... please post the relevant code in order to help us to help you

Comment: MVVMLight `RaisePropertyChanged` is a implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged`, See here: http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#V3/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight (NET35)/ViewModelBase.cs, so I believe it will do the same thing here when *using either null or String.Empty as the property name in the PropertyChangedEventArgs.*

Comment: @Bolu a glance at the source code would say otherwise.  It looks like it still will throw an exception if you pass either null or String.Empty if built in Debug.

Comment: @DavidL, I thought `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` only affects Debug mode, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @Bolu, no you are correct.  It will only throw an exception in Debug mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVVM Light seems to have a checkthat will check if the property name you have passed in exists.  This doesn't make sense in this case.

A quick search shows an [issue logged on the CodePlex site](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/workitem/6993) and marked as closed & fixed and it does seem to be fixed in the latest codebase.  What version are you using?

If you can't upgrade, I suppose you could add your own invocator (note the protected `PropertyChangedHandler` accessor exists in 5.x, I have no idea if it exists in your version).

```
private void RaiseAllPropertiesChanged()
{
    var handler = PropertyChangedHandler;

    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(string.Empty));            
    }
}
```

If you're using V3, it seems there's no solution (`PropertyChangedHandler` does not exist and the property verification will throw the exception you're seeing).  As this seems to be a known bug that's been fixed, I'd suggest using a later version.

Comment: Your code seems very interesting. When I try it, I get a compile error: "The event 'ObservableObject.PropertyChanged' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=". It seems that it is picking the one of GalaSoft!

Comment: Yes, `PropertyChanged` is an event, so you can't use that to invoke an event from a derived class.  In the code I was reading, there is an accessor `PropertyChangedHandler` that would allow this (this is what's in the code above).  It may or may not exist in your version.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about MVVM-Light but here is what you can do with .net fx 4.5 + :

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

class SomeClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int somefield;

    public int SomeProperty
    {
        get { return somefield; }
        set 
        {
            somefield = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
}
```

Comment: Alternative theres the Fody Framework that implements INotifyPropertyChanged with simple attributes... https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged

Comment: I prefer to stick with MvvmLight because of all other benefits

Answer (score 0):

Having recently come across this issue wiht MvvmLight 5.3, I was perplexed why the following was not updating all of the bound properties on my UI:

```
RaisePropertyChanged();
```

In fact, in order to update all properties, an empty `string` must be passed into `RaisePropertyChanged`, at which point all properties will update:

```
RaisePropertyChanged(string.Empty);
```